# Using java write two methods min and max to find maximum value and minimum value in linked list but the input list is array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list, max, min

- *I want to write two methods min and max to find maximum value of a node and minimum value of a node in linked list.*
- *for example if a variable called abc stores { 1, 78, -9, 42 , 0, 14} then abc.min() should return -9 and abc.max() should return 78.*
- *If the list is empty it should return -1. Print the returned value.*

  **Please help me in this how I can compute max and min values in a linked list by inputting array of integers**

  ````
  ```package demo;

    public class MaximumMinimum {

     class Node{  
          int data;  
          Node next;  

      public Node(int data) {  
          this.data = data;  
          this.next = null;  
      }  
  }  

  //Represent the head and tail of the singly linked list 
      public Node head = null;  
      public Node tail = null;  

     //addNode() will add a new node to the list  
     public void addNode(int data) {  
         //Create a new node  
         Node newNode = new Node(data);  

        //Checks if the list is empty  
      if(head == null) {  
          //If list is empty, both head and tail will point to new node  
          head = newNode;  
          tail = newNode;  
      }  
      else {  
          //newNode will be added after tail such that tail's next will point to newNode  
          tail.next = newNode;  
          //newNode will become new tail of the list  
          tail = newNode;  
      }  
  }  

  //minNode() will find out the minimum value node in the list  
  public void minNode() {  
      Node current = head;  
      int min;  

      if(head == null) {  
          System.out.println("List is empty");  
      }  
      else {  
          //Initializing min with head node data  
          min = head.data;  

          while(current != null){  
               //If current node's data is smaller than min  
               //Then, replace value of min with current node's data  
               if(min > current.data) {  
                   min = current.data;  
               }  
               current= current.next;  
          }  
          System.out.println("Minimum value node in the list: "+ min);  
      }  
  }  

  //maxNode() will find out the maximum value node in the list  
  public void maxNode() {  
      Node current = head;  
      int max;  

      if(head == null) {  
          System.out.println("List is empty");  
      }  
      else {  
          //Initializing max with head node data  
          max = head.data;  

          while(current != null){  
               //If current node's data is greater than max  
               //Then, replace value of max with current node's data  
               if(max < current.data) {  
                   max = current.data;  
               }  
               current = current.next;  
          }  
          System.out.println("Maximum value node in the list: "+ max);  
      }  
  }  

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      MaximumMinimum sList = new MaximumMinimum(); 

      //Adds data to the list  
      sList.addNode(5);  
      sList.addNode(8);  
      sList.addNode(1);  
      sList.addNode(6);  

      //Display the minimum value node in the list  
      sList.minNode();  

      *//Display the maximum value node in the list *
      sList.maxNode();  
      }  
    }  ```
  ````

Comment: Do you need handmade implemenation? Or you can use Comparator?

Comment: I want complete executable code for the above problem.

Comment: just read about comparable or take collection and sort your elements and get first - min, last - max

Comment: Yeah comparator is also fine but the input to the linked list is an array of integers i.e. a variable int[ ] abc = { 1, 78, -9, 42 , 0, 14}

Comment: Arrays.asList(here your array) = List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code you given is executing in correct manner.

**You can also use**

```
MaximumMinimum sList = new MaximumMinimum(); 
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Node head = sList.head;
while(head != null){
    list.add(head.data);
    head= head.next;
}
//no recommended if you want to design your own method    
System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(Collections.max(list));
System.out.println(Collections.min(list));
```

**For inputting array of integers to**

```
public void stores(int[] array)
{
    for(int element:array)
    {
        this.addNode(element);
    }
}
```

then if you run in main

```
 int[] elements = {1, 78, -9, 42 , 0, 14};
    sList.stores(elements);
    sList.maxNode(); //78
    sList.minNode();//-9
```

Also you can use `Arrays.stream(array_name).forEach(e->sList.add(e))` if You want to do it in java 8 way.

Comment: Thank you so much Aashish Pawar!! Code is working perfect !!

Comment: You are welcome feel free to ask question please do upvote if you liked my approach

Answer (score 0):

**You put a greater than sign for `minNode()` function and a lesser than for `maxNode()`.**

```
public void minNode() {  
    Node current = head;  
    int min;  

    if(head == null) {  
        System.out.println("List is empty");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing min with head node data  
        min = head.data;  

        while(current != null){  
             //If current node's data is smaller than min  
             //Then, replace value of min with current node's data  


            // Your error was here:

             min = Math.min(min, current.data); // You can simplify updating min to this.




             current= current.next;  
        }  
        System.out.println("Minimum value node in the list: "+ min);  
    }  
}
```

And `maxNode()` becomes this:

```
public void maxNode() {  
    Node current = head;  
    int max;  

    if(head == null) {  
        System.out.println("List is empty");  
    }  
    else {  
        //Initializing max with head node data  
        max = head.data;  

        while(current != null){  
             //If current node's data is greater than max  
             //Then, replace value of max with current node's data  


             // Your error was here:

             max = Math.max(max, current.data); // And updating max becomes this.




             current = current.next;  
        }  
        System.out.println("Maximum value node in the list: "+ max);  
    }  
}
```